# C# how to get dll assembly information?

Tags: c#, dll, reflection, dll-injection

If we want to get the version number of a dll we could use,

```
Assembly assembly = Assembly.LoadFrom("System.Xml");
Version ver = assembly.GetName().Version;
```

How to get the other information (like AssemblyTitle, AssemblyProduct, etc..) ?

[image: using Reflecter.exe]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
var attribute = assembly.GetCustomAttribute<AssemblyTitleAttribute>();
var title = attribute.Title;
```

to get the attribute. And same solution for `AssemblyProductAttribute`.